# Android: tabSelectedTextColor doesn't change text of selected tab in TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I m trying to change the text Color of the selected tab in Tab Layout. The indicator color works fine, but the tabSelectedTextColor doesn't seems to be working. The color remains white. I am using support library 22.2.1, what am I doing wrong? Is there an alternate way to achieve this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="#000000"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="#000000"
                app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

Comment: The latest is `23.3.0`. You set the color to black, what color did you want?

Comment: Yes I wanted black, but it shows white, only tab Indicator color changes. Text always remains white. I don't want to move to 23.3.0 right now as a lot of other changes would be required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not exactly know what is causing your code to not work, but I have got an alternate way to do it.

The other way to do it is to change the selected tab's color in your code programmatically. You can use the `setTabTextColors (int normalColor, int selectedColor)` method of the `TabLayout` (found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setTabTextColors(int,%20int))) and not only set selected text color but normal text color too.

So, your code could go something like this:

```
yourTabLayout.setTabTextColors (Color.White, Color.Black);
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) are the colors defined.

I hope this helps you.