# set textcolor of tab

Tags: android, android-tablayout

why am I not able to set the textcolor of the tablayout?

Here is the whole xml-source. The relevant line is:

```
 app:tabTextColor="@color/tabTextColor"
```

The text is not white - its black

And here is the whole source coude

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#4f83cc"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/tabTextColor"
        >
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
```

and in the color-xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="colorPrimary">#01579b</color>
   <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#002f6c</color>
   <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
   <color name="tabTextColor">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Why marked as duplicate? I've already tried that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chnage text color of TabLayout using java code

```
tabLayout.setTabTextColors(
  getResources().getColor(R.color.your_unselected_text_color),
  getResources().getColor(R.color.your_selected_text_color)
);
```

Or You can try custom style for TabLayout

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
  <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabText</item>
  <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/tab_text_act</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
  <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_text</item>
</style>
```

and here is code

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout" />
```

Comment: I've tried but get Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

Comment: well I may accept this answer since it worked after moving the style to my values-21 folder. I can see at android.developer that TabLayout was added in API 22. thanks and I cannot see WHY my question was marked as duplicate - look now, my new question about the same issue solved the problem!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
     app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
     app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
```

If it still doesn't work do it programmatically : https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/36962857

I hope this helps you.